# Unable to connect my spring boot application to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have got this access denied exception :

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)
>            org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to
>   obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException:
>   Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>            018-08-23 00:55:21.791  INFO 1260 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container
>   EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 2018-08-23
>   00:55:21.813  INFO 1260 --- [           main]
>   o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing
>   PersistenceUnitInfo [     name: default   ...] 2018-08-23 00:55:22.180 
>   INFO 1260 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version
>   : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final} 2018-08-23 00:55:22.181 
>   INFO 1260 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment
>   : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found 2018-08-23 00:55:22.221 
>   INFO 1260 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version
>   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final} 2018-08-23
>   00:55:22.351  INFO 1260 --- [           main]
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
>   2018-08-23 00:55:23.445 ERROR 1260 --- [           main]
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception
>   during pool initialization.

application properties file:

```
    spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

    #===============================
    #DATA SOURCE
    #===============================

    #set here configurations for the database connection

    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstoredatabase?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true
    #username and secret
    spring.datasource.data.username=root
    spring.datasource.data.password=

    #keep connection alive if idle for long time
    spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
    spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1


    #===================
    #jpa/hibernate
    #===================
    #use spring.jpa.properties.* for hibernate native properties
    #stripped before adding them to the entity manager

    #show or not log for each sql query
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true

    #jdbc driver class
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

    #the project
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create


    #allows hibernate to generat sql optimised for particular dbms
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

---

my java file:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BookstoreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BookstoreApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is you are not able to connect to your local database, you can check this issue in multiple front 1. whether url `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstoredatabase?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true` is proper, if not check with simple jdbc way of connecting db 2. is your local DB password protected(default its not, but incase), 3. get proper dialect from : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your database username and password are not set with correct property names, as in spring-boot the name of the properties are predefined and only those should be used while giving configuration information. Just try below property keys for username and password :

```
spring.datasource.username = 
spring.datasource.password =
```

Provide appropriate values..

Answer (score 1):

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

It seems your user  password is incorrect. Try to login MySQL with same credentials and it will display the same error.

Comment: I'm blinded with trust, username/password are incorrect. Now my issue got resolved